# I want to know concept Entity Metadata Descriptor XML File

Tags: xml, spring

I searched and read an article https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wxs/8.6.1?topic=files-entity-metadata-descriptor-xml-file but I don't understand what it is.
There are some terms like: id, basic, element, class id? What are those for? I need to explain in detail their purpose and Some example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be mixing up items here. As the documentation you provide is for WebSphere eXtreme scale, but your picture is describing the @Entity annotation for JPA.

If you would like more information about JPA I suggest this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/learn-jpa-hibernate

And this one for something geared more toward Spring:
https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

If you want a sandbox to try features out with I suggest utilizing Springs integration with H2 (an in memory datastore). Note that you will also be utilizing HikariCP for connection pooling by default in Spring.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database

HikariCP:
https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp

These should allow you to build a decent foundation in JPA with Spring Boot. Always keep in mind there is good documentation provided within the classes as well, utilize your IDE to view the annotation sources to find good information on available parameters quickly.

Comment: sorry my fault, i am wanting to know more about xml descriptor. And also can you give me an example of splitting into 2 times one to many, instead of many to many?

Comment: I must admit, I am a little confused on what you are referring to as a xml descriptor. However, as for the second portion of your comment here is an article describing in detail the `@OneToMany` (as well as the reverse to that) `@ManyToOne` relationship in JPA. Keep in mind if you are planning to display the output of a bi-directional relationship, you will need to handle the circular reference or your output may infinitely recurse on each other.

Article: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: If you are looking for the API documentation for Spring JPA it is located here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/

ref: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data